# Cant install Grandnode

Tags: c#

when I try to install `grandnode`, it gives me this error.

> A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using
>   CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = ReadPreferenceServerSelector{
>   ReadPreference = { Mode : Primary } }, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{
>   AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster
>   state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "Automatic", Type :
>   "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId
>   : 1, EndPoint : "123.223.223.11:27111" }", EndPoint:
>   "123.223.223.11:27111", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown",
>   HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An
>   exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. --->
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoAuthenticationException: Unable to authenticate
>   username 'testing' on database 'grandnodetest'. --->
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command authenticate failed:
>   auth fails. at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.ProcessReply(ConnectionId
>   connectionId, ReplyMessage`1 reply) at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.d__11.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.MongoDBCRAuthenticator.d__7.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.MongoDBCRAuthenticator.d__7.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Authentication.AuthenticationHelper.d__1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.d__3.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__48.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__48.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task
>   task) at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.d__27.MoveNext()"
>   }] }

can anyone help me with this? I am running the project from local.

Please and Thank you.

Comment: Well, its saying it cant connect to your MogoDB, is that alive and well.. it says testing on grandnotetest isnt working... Have you checked everything that end?

Comment: @BugFinder yes is alive, it even created the database 'grandnodetest' inside MongoDb, but it is giving me this error.

Comment: and testing has access to the grandnodetest, from your machine?

Comment: @BugFinder testing is my MongoDBUsername

Comment: yes, I guessed that - but it clearly says Unable to authenticate username 'testing' on database 'grandnodetest'

Comment: @BugFinder but I always use the username 'testing' to access to my database in Robomongo

Comment: Well, the facts are it says it cant authenticate against that DB..

Comment: what is the reason causing it?

Comment: You seem unwilling to look for the answer. I cant help you if you wont

Comment: I am trying to look for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an older version of MongoDB than is supported by your application. Please use MongoDB version 3.0 or higher and try again. If the problem happens again, please reach out to me on our support.